# Understanding Django Rest Framework's ModelViewSet Router

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have my `Comment model`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    """A comment is a content shared by a user in some post.""" 

    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the comment str."""
        return "'{}'".format(self.content)
```

Its serializer:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Comment model serializer."""

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new comment in some post, by request.user."""

        validated_data['user'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super().create(validated_data)

    def list(self, request):
        """List all the comments from some post."""

        if 'post' not in request.query_params:
            raise ValidationError('Post id must be provided.')

        q = self.queryset.filter(post=request.query_params['post'])
        serializer = CommentSerializer(q, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The viewset:

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()

    def get_permissions(self):
        permissions = []
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permissions.append(IsAuthenticated)
        return [p() for p in permissions]

    def get_object(self):
        """Return comment by primary key."""
        return get_object_or_404(Comment, id=self.kwargs['pk'])  # this is the drf's get_object_or_404 function

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Delete a comment created by request.user from a post."""
        pdb.set_trace()
        instance = self.get_object()
        if instance.user != request.user:
            raise ValidationError('Comment does not belong to the authenticated user.')
        self.perform_destroy(instance)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

So far so good when it comes to list, create and retrieve. But when it comes to delete/destroy (Idk the difference) I don't know how to get the URL for the `DELETE request`.
I'm using **Postman** to do so.

Urls.py:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet, basename='comments')

pdb.set_trace()  # Put a pdb here to see what does router.urls have.

urlpatterns = [
    # Non api/simple django views
    path('create_comment/', create_comment, name='create_comment'),
    path('delete_comment/', delete_comment, name='delete_comment'),
    # rest api views
    path('rest/', include(router.urls))
]
```

When I debug the `router.urls`, the terminal shows this:

```
[<URLPattern '^comments/$' [name='comments-list']>, <URLPattern '^comments/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$' [name='comments-detail']>]
```

Why there is no `url` for `create` and `destroy`?
I could create some Comments from the api, and I didn't even know how did I get the `POST request url` for the `create` function, I just guessed lol, but that's not what you want when you're programming right?
I have checked the [Routers documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) but I don't get it. Please give some help! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, Django uses the **`comments-list`** list for *create and list* operation and **`comments-detail`** for *update and delete* operations.

That is, there are only two URL end-points, but it supports several actions, which can be performed by *changing the HTTP methods*

You can use 
**`HTTP GET foo-bar/comments/`** to retrieve all comments where as 
**`HTTP POST foo-bar/comments/`** can be used to create a new comment.